# Hide horizontal ruler in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, rulers, photran

How can I hide this horizontal ruler (outlined in red) along the top of my (Fortran) source code? Looks like it might be related to printer settings, but I can't find anything.
[image: Eclipse IDE]
Using Eclipse Photon Milestone 5 (4.8.0M5) on Ubuntu 17.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ***Window > Preferences: Fortran > Editor* uncheck** the ***Enable horizontal ruler*** check box.

See [*Fortran Development User Guide - Writing Code*, section *Configuring The Editor*](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.photran.doc.user/html/basic/WritingCode.html)

Comment: Thanks! Oddly this option didn't appear when I searched for the word "ruler".

Comment: @MasterHD Probably, the keywords you used (which are used for filtering) are missing in the preference dialog page. If you like, [you can submit a feature request to add these keywords here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=PTP&component=Photran.Editor%20%26%20Outline%20View).